# /etc/X11/xorg.conf keeps getting renamed?

Tags: xorg, xubuntu, 14.04

I am using `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to configure [xf86-input-mtrack](https://github.com/BlueDragonX/xf86-input-mtrack/blob/master/README.md).

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf` keeps getting renamed after every 4 or so reboots. For example, it was renamed to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.0426201` recently. Why does this happen?

Comment: Maybe you want to use the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory instead? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) two packages that might do this:

1. `/usr/bin/gpu-manager` in ubuntu-drivers-common can replace `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` if it doesn't find the right contents in it ([LP #1310489](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1310489)). If the generated settings doesn't conflict with your own edits, it's easiest to just leave them in.
2. The nvidia-prime package does this on upgrade. If you have automatic package updates and reboot seldom, it could explain your observations.

   I don't know the reason, but I regard it as a bug - opened [LP #1345585](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1345585).

Both rename the old `xorg.conf` to `xorg.conf.MMDDYYYY`.